# basic boost date_time input format question

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

I've got a pointer to a string, (char *) as input. The date/time looks like this:
Sat, 10 Apr 2010 19:30:00
I'm only interested in the date, not the time.
I created an "input_facet" with the format I want:

```
boost::date_time::date_input_facet inFmt("%a %d %b %Y");
```

but I'm not sure what to do with it. Ultimately I'd like to create a date object from the string. I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track with that input facet and format, but I have no idea how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: :O  I just googled "boost date time input" and got this post...3rd result. Am I famous now? It only took google 10 minutes to index this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't always dismiss the time part of a string due to time zone differences a date can change.

- to parse date/time you could use `time_input_facet<>`
- to extract a date part from it you could use `.date()` method

#### Example:

```
// $ g++ *.cc -lboost_date_time && ./a.out 
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
 
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  using boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet;
  using boost::posix_time::ptime;

  stringstream ss;
  ss <<                                     "Sat, 10 Apr 2010 19:30:00";
  ss.imbue(locale(locale::classic(),       
                  new local_time_input_facet("%a, %d %b %Y " "%H:%M:%S")));
  ptime t;
  ss.exceptions(ios::failbit);
  ss >> t;
  cout << "date: " << t.date() << '\n' ;
}
```

Run it:

```
$ g++ *.cc -lboost_date_time && ./a.out 
date: 2010-Apr-10
```